# Cross compile ROS to ARM (OC8 Module)

Tags: slam, navigation, compile, gmapping, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I need to cross compile ROS and, after that, use SLAM.

I have an OC8 Modulee (ARM9) with a embedded linux kernel ([www.opencontroller.com/modules.html](http://www.opencontroller.com/modules.html)).

I've read so much about it, including everything about cross compiling in ros.org.

Some idea how can I do that? Really need help.

Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/70501/cross-compile-ros-to-arm-(oc8-module)/) by [Cássio](https://answers.ros.org/users/5385/c%C3%A1ssio/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-08-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd suggest looking into the Meta ROS project: https://github.com/bmwcarit/meta-ros

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0